# I am getting an error while using DISTINCT in the select query

Tags: sql, hive

I'm getting an error while running the DISTINCT on the column in select query on HIVE tables

select distinct column123 from table123;

select distinct column123 from table123;

I can only see part of the error message

> [Cloudera]HiveJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: ERROR_STATE, SQL state: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask, Query: SELECT DISTINCT `default_encounter_tmp_p`.`df2_c_1000b_nm1_rcvr_nm_hdr` FROM `default`.`encounter_tmp_p` `default_encounter_tmp_p`.

Comment: Are you trying to run more than one query in a single call? I don't know about Hive, but many SQL interfaces don't allow that.

Comment: No, just a simple command